# Override or remove the appTheme CSS injected into a Buildfire App

Tags: javascript, dom, buildfire

So I faced the challenge of created a large custom app through the Buildfire platform. The client had a lot of custom element styles that were being overridden by the appTheme settings in the dashboard, and overriding these styles in traditional CSS fashion was growing to be a monumental task.

I wrote this small function to remove the custom styles injected into the application and so far all of the client's custom styling is showing correctly.

I figured I would share this with the community since this has been an issue without resolution for our team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to disable the appTheme CSS in your plugin, you can simply use a meta tag in the widget's HTML, like so:

```
<meta name="buildfire" content="disableTheme">
```

This is covered the SDK wiki under the [meta tag](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/BuildFire-MetaTags) section.

Comment: thanks, I did find this after I posted. I was late to the party.

Answer (score 1):

This code is inside my index.html file for the AngularJS Application.

```
<body ng-controller="mainController" onload="removeCustomCSS()">
<script>
    function removeCustomCSS() {
      let links = document.querySelectorAll('[href*=appTheme]');
      links[0].remove();
    }
</script>
```